# Is electrons ability to produce mechanical motion considered the only reason for it to be material particle?

Tags: particle-physics, material-science

"Cathode rays (streams of electrons) produce mechanical motion of a small paddle wheel placed in their path indicating that they are material particles."$_1$ Isn't this statement wrong?

Assuming electrons to be material particles, "if we use light to observe the position of electron, photons can transfer momentum to the electron at the time of collision"$_2$. Isn't here photon causing mechanical motion of electron? Then we can also consider photon to be material particle based on the above reasoning of considering electron to be material particle. Isn't it? I don't think photon is considered to be a material particle. Is it a material particle?

So, is the first quote correct that electron can be considered as a material particle only because of its ability to produce mechanical motion?

---

Reference: $_1$Principles of Physcial Chemistry-Puri, Sharma, Pathania-Page No.21. $_2$ Modern's abc of Chemistry-Dr.S.P.Jauhar-Page No.169. *Data is subjected to modification without the loss of meaning up to my knowledge and page no's may change depending on editions.*

Comment: Not very well phrased, I agree. On the other hand, what you call "material particle" is just a matter of definition. In my book, fermions are matter particles, bosons with spin 1 (e.g. photons) are force carrier particles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short-short version:

We can measure the mass of electrons. They have some. Surely that is enough.

### Details:

To perform the measurement obtain a beam of electrons of known energy. You can know the energy either by knowing the accelerating potential or by measuring the energy with a [velocity selector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_filter). Pass the beam through a region of known and constant magnetic field but zero electric field and note [the radius of curvature](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/maspec.html#c2).

This is the method used by most mass spectrometers, albeit tuned for much more massive projectiles.

You must also know the value of the charge on the electron. [Millikan's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment) will work but is difficult to do well.

Comment: "*We can measure the mass of electrons. They have some. Surely that is enough.*"- But, electron's probability to be in the place of neutron, leaves me this to be not enough.

Comment: What? That comment makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, if that was not clear. From my acquaintance, mass of any particle can be said as the impenetrable tangible substance that goes into the makeup of a physical object. If electron can be said to stay in place of neutron, it is against to the acquaintance of what we mean by mass. Or otherwise, is mass defined in other way?

Comment: I still do not follow *"If electron can be said to stay in place of neutron"*. There is no relationship between a neutron and an electron. Electrons are leptons and fundamental, neutrons are baryons and are made of quarks.

Comment: Thank you for the time, I have understood the complexity (definition of mass/material, 0-D "point" particle, photon collision, etc) from the discussion with you. I will post a new question when I get clear picture.

Answer (score 3):

The electron and the photon are [elementary particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particles), quantum mechanical entities, which given the boundary conditions of the setup will sometimes display characteristics of particles, i.e. trajectories and impact points, and sometimes display characteristics of probability waves, as in the two slit experiment.

In impact situations where only the momentum is measured they behave like classical particles which carry momentum, both the photon and the electron. In interference experiments the probability distributions of the measurements display wave properties, even though we are talking of the same "particles".

Within this description the adjective "material" has no physical meaning.